# Header se ensancha y luego se reduce al cargar sitio web en Divi

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Estoy teniendo un problema en un sitio web construido con Wordpress y usando el tema Divi.

Resulta que al cargar el sitio web por primera vez, el header se muestra más ancho de lo que debe ser y posteriormente se reduce. Este efecto dura menos de un segundo, pero se ve mal en cuanto a la presentación del sitio.

El sitio web es [www.clinicadentalauris.cl](http://www.clinicadentalauris.cl). Si no visualizan el problema, recarguen con Ctrl+F5 para que borre la caché.

Quisiera saber si a alguien le ha pasado este problema y sabe una solución, ya que he buscado en español y en inglés y no he encontrado alguien que le pase eso en específico, ya que Divi suele tener problemas de carga, pero son de otro tipo, y para esos problemas sí encuentro solución.

La versión de Divi es la 4.8.2

Agradezco te antemano al que pueda responderme eso.

PD: tengo los siguientes códigos agregados en el  de todas las páginas del sitio:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var elm=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
elm.style.display="none";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event) {elm.style.display="block"; });
</script>

    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var totalheight = 0;
jQuery(".et-l--header .et_builder_inner_content .et_pb_section").each(function(){
totalheight = totalheight + jQuery(this).outerHeight();
});
totalheight = totalheight + "px";
jQuery("#et-main-area").css("padding-top",0);
});
</script>
```